# Returning values of a function in R

Tags: r, function

I have the following function:

```
chatty <- function(f) {
  function(x, ...) {
    res <- f(x, ...)
    cat("Processing ", x, "\n", sep = "")
    res
  }
}

f <- function(x) x ^ 2
```

why does the following function call return 2 values instead?

```
chatty(f)(1)

Processing 1
[1] 1
```

From my understanding of function, it should only return a single value/vector only.

Moreover, adding further lines seems to overwrite the previous line res also.

```
chatty <- function(f) {
  function(x, ...) {
    res <- f(x, ...)
    cat("Processing ", x, "\n", sep = "")
    res
    3
  }
}

 f <- function(x) x ^ 2

chatty(f)(1)

Processing 1
[1] 3
```

My question would be on how does a function return a value in R for this case?

Comment: "why does the following function call return 2 values instead?": I can see only 1 value returned (3).

Comment: @nicola sorry for the typo, I have not included the definition of function f in the previous version. I guess my question would be on why is it possible to return a text and a value in a function and if having subsequent values will override the previous.

Comment: Text being `cat`ted to the console isn't a value being returned, you don't get that text when you assign the results to a variable. R returns the value of the last line/expression of a function unless you explicitly `return()` something else, and functions only ever return single values.

Comment: When it looks like functions are returning multiple values, all those values are being put in a list, and then the list is returned.

Comment: Please fix your first example. I was wondering how 1² can return 3 until I run the example myself and got the expected result instead.